# Cannot receive push notifications from Firebase on iOS (work everywhere else)

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

The push notifications works on foreground and background on :

Android Chrome (browser and standalone)
Mac Desktop : Firefox, Chrome, Safari
But on iOs, the message seems to not be received by the service worker nor the client.
No errors or abnormal messages are visible on the dev console.

```
Browser Version
Safari 17.2
Firebase SDK Version
9.15.0
Firebase SDK Product:
Messaging
```

[image]

**Code to reproduce issue**

I followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@sumanthegde123/web-push-notifications-with-react-and-firebase-with-safari-error-handling-d2979d10c9ac) where you can simply [clone his repo](https://github.com/KILROY007/Firebase-web-notification/tree/master)

1. $ firebase Init
2. Enable Firebase Cloud Messaging and generate a VAPID Key.
3. Enable Hosting
4. Get the firebase configuration infos.
   5 .Create an .env file with your firebase configuration info and VAPID KEY:

```
REACT_APP_FB_API_KEY=
REACT_APP_FB_AUTH_DOMAIN=
REACT_APP_FB_PROJECT_ID=
REACT_APP_FB_STORAGE_BUCKET=
REACT_APP_FB_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=
REACT_APP_FB_APP_ID=

REACT_APP_FB_VAPID_KEY=
```

6. $ npm run build ; firebase deploy
7. Access to the url, (for ios do "Add to Homepage", and open as a standalone first)
8. click on "enable notifications"
9. Wait for the token on the dev console (can take up to 20seconds)
10. Copy the token and paste it on FCM dashboard to Send a message